# web service messages consumed by other service

Tags: wcf, msmq, appfabric

I Have a .NET 4.5 WCF web service that consumes messages from a local private MSMQ queue running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with AppFabric installed.

This service reads the messages of the queue and processes the files referenced in the message, i have used AppFabric to throttle the service to process 16 concurrent messages, 8 on each AppPool worker process.

The AppPool is uses a domain account that has full privileges on the network share where the files to be processed are stored.

This service has been working fine for years, except in the last week the ~90% of the files its been asked to process have failed with either a UnauthorizedAccessException.

This behavior was exhibited across all of the services on that application server, no matter which file server the service was asked to process files from. Even files that had previously processed file were now failing.

Comment: I have a very interesting answer but apparently i can't post it for 8 hours, apologies if you have the same issue.

Comment: No I meant someone downvoted your question without leaving a comment which is quite rude. However, I upvoted your question leaving you with a net question score of 0. Am looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Maybe the down vote was because the title describes the underlying problem rather than the symptoms described, i guess we'll never know

Answer (score 1):

After a long a fruitless weekend searching and hacking of various different things including:

- Shared Folder Permissions and Quotas
- Windows Licencing (CALs etc)
- Firewalls
- Various software patches to the Web app

I eventually discovered the actual issue by accident, whilst redeploying the Web app i noticed something odd. When i stopped the web app via the WCF menu in IIS, the messages continued to be consumed so i stopped the stopped the app pool running the web service, but the messages continue to be consumed, I though this might be due to the large latency added to MQMQ message state by the Distributed transaction service when lots of messages are rolled back to the poison message queue, so i went to lunch. When i came back the messages were still being consumed and process explorer confirmed the apppool running my server was no longer executing.

Something was clearly up but it was uncertain weather this was the cause, a symptom or a coincidence. The clincher was when i throttled my service back to only process one message at a time to see if the access, to the share was reaching some sort of limit, I noticed that failure rate went up to ~98%. This suggested that something else was processing the messages and failing, but also reporting those failures into my reporting system in a way only my application could.

I little further investigation revealed that the default application pool used to serve the default web site, was also executing my WCF web service but failing to access the files on the file server as the identity used to run the default application pool had no privileges the failures took less time the than the successful file processes therefor the slower i made my service go the more messages were failed by the default app pool.

**The Cause**

Whilst i was adjusting the throttling on my web app, i inadvertently set the throttling or the default web site that was the parent to the web application, i noticed this strait away and reset them back to the default value. What i hadn't realized at the time was that this had added a `<system.servicemodel>` tag to the web config of the default website. The outcome of which was that my default web site started to behave like a web application and for reasons i am yet to understand, it started to execute the functionality of its child web application, it may be related to the WAS activation, all i know is that i was most certainly not the desired behavior.

**The Fix**

I removed the `<system.servicemodel>` tag and its contents from the web.conf of the default website and removed net.msmq from its list of enabled protocols and everything is back to normal.